# How can I make selected item in listbox scroll to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I creating a simple list off of array items. Scroll bars will appear if the list is big. However, my question is - when an item is selected, I would like to see that item to the top of the visible position, pushing all above items hidden above under scrollbar. So no matter what I item I select, it should be on top of the visible list box. This is not same as positioning the item to the top, just on the scrolling top. Hope my question is understood here.

Thanks for any help or direction I can get.

Comment: Do you have any code you could share?  An attempt perhaps, or at least something to go off of?

Comment: I was actually going to create jsfiddle, and next thing I know Borre provided the solution for this.

Comment: Please mark his answer as accepted then. :) There is a check mark you can click to the left of the question.

Comment: Actually I just got to 15 points, so now I can mark answer as accepted (which I did).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$('#scrollable li').on('click', function(e){
    $('#scrollable').animate({scrollTop: $(e.target).position().top + $('#scrollable').scrollTop()});
});
```

See also this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/729nX/1/

Comment: OMG! Thats exactly what I was looking for. You are awesome Borre. The fact that you created jsfiddle is even awesome. That is so fast.

Answer (score 4):

after much googling, 
i found you can either use [scrollTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) using javascript with a code similar to this

```
function scrollToElem(elem) {    
    if(pageElement != null){               
        window.scrollTo(elem.offsetTop, 0);    
    }
}
var elem= document.getElementById('your_element');
scrollToElem(elem);
```

or use use [location.hash](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp) which seems to me the simplest solution
with something alone the lines of

```
location.hash = '#' + 'your_element';
```

Answer (score 1):

in case you have a scroll bar in an element instead of the whole window.

[Element.scrollTop - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop)

[Element.scrollTop - W3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp)

```
function onSelect(list, selectedItem){
    list.scrollTop = selectedItem.offsetTop - list.offsetTop;
}
```