# Angularjs custom dropdown scroll to value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[How can I make selected item in listbox scroll to the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19870134/how-can-i-make-selected-item-in-listbox-scroll-to-the-top)

[http://jsfiddle.net/729nX/1/

Some thing familiar to this but with a few changes :
1) using only angular, without jq.
2) my code is different.

```
<span class="custom-list-wrapper" ng-show="openDropDown"> 
    <span class="custom-list">
        <span class="list-object ng-binding ng-scope selected" ng-repeat="(key, value) in countries " data-value="AUT" ng-click="changeCountry({data: value.name})" ng-class="{selected : selected.name == value.name}">
                Austria
         </span>
```

This is how it looks on my side:

```
<span class="custom-list-wrapper" ng-show="openDropDown"> 
    <span class="custom-list" >
         <span class="list-object" ng-repeat="(key, value) in countries " data-value="{{key}}"  ng-class="{selected : selected.name == value.name}">
                {{value.name}}
         </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

This is a really long list and i want to scroll to the specific item in the dropdown, some thing like in the fiddle

```
    /*  var scrollToSelected = function(){
    //  angular.element('.custom-list').animate({scrollTop : angular.element(xxx)},1000);

    angular.element('.custom-list').animate({
        scrollTop: angular.element('span[value="AUT"]').offset().top
    }, 1000);

}
```

i tried this but got a jqlite error.

Would happy to hear any solution :)

Comment: you aren't using jQuery?

Comment: yes im not using jquery

Answer (score 0):

As you aren't using `JQuery`, you should look into how jQLite work. The way jQLite works is, it can only query to predefined `tagName` & `element` of HTML. For `custom-class` & `selector` based query you have to use `native-browser` API to get a DOM.

```
var customList = document.getElementsByClassName('custom-list'),
    spanAut    = document.querySelector('span[value="AUT"]');
angular.element(customList).animate({
    scrollTop: angular.element(spanAut).prop('offsetTop')
}, 1000);
```